# i want to use left outer join in mongodb, how to use it? i'm using mongodb compass only

Tags: mongodb, join

I'm new to MongoDB I need to use join query in MongoDB but everyone says can't use join query. But how to use, how to write a query in MongoDB compass.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about the issue you faced when using the joins. If you want to do joins like sql i think you cant do it cause it is not a relational database as you know. But you can do similar to joins by using [Aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) or [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in mongoose.
Moreover if you want to use compass to write queries use the query bar, here is the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/query-bar/) attached to how to write query in query bar. To perform Aggregation using compass use the aggregations tab in collection. Hope this helps you atleast resolve some of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in Compass, but possible with Studio 3T: [How to Create MongoDB Joins Using SQL](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/create-mongodb-joins-with-sql/#left-outer-joins)